Particle A and B are connected with an Extensible, massless, string - why are the accelerations for A and B different?
Let’s consider two blocks, A and B, traveling in straight 1D motion.
Particle A is driving forwards with B connected behind it.
A and B are connected with an extensible string parallel to the direction of motion (i.e. the string can be extended), and we can assume the mass of the string is negligible.
Now since the string has mass=0, this would suggest the tension in the string is the same throughout the string, applying Newton’s second law. Tension driving the string’s center of mass forwards, subtract the tension in the other direction must be equal to 0.
And so I’m really confused how the extensibility of the string implies that the acceleration for both particles A and B are different?
If the tensions that A and B experience at either end of the string are the same, how can it be true that A and B accelerate at different values?

What would you expect to happen if instead of a "string" there were a "spring" connecting them?

@BowlOfRed intuitively I would expect A to be moving forwards, the spring to start extending and B to remain at rest. But I don’t understand how this could work, because surely B needs to move forwards too due to the tension in the spring pulling it forwards?

The force that the string exerts on A is equal and opposite to the force that it exerts on B. So if A and B have the same mass, they have equal and opposite accelerations. But not so if their masses are different, because their accelerations are in inverse proportion to their masses. We have $$\vec {F_B}=-\vec{F_A}\ \ \ \ \text {so, using Newton's Law 2,}\ \ \ \ m_B\vec{a_B}=-m_A\vec{a_A}\ \ \\ \text {so}\ \ \ \frac{a_B}{a_A}=\frac{m_A}{m_B}$$
in which $a_B$ and $a_A$ are the magnitudes of the bodies' accelerations.

Apologies but why is the acceleration of object B the negative of object A's acceleration? I would have imagined if object A is driving the motion forwards by accelerating, then surely object B would not be decelerating?

The accelerations above assume that string tension is the only force on the objects.   From the statement "Particle A is driving forwards", that may not be true.  It could be that some unspecified "driving" force is sufficient to make both accelerations equal.

You're quite right, of course.

@BowlOfRed Sorry I should have made my question clearer - let;s assume the question specifies that there is a some large driving force D, acting on object A, travelling in a straight line. So my question is why would, in general, A and B have different values of acceleration?

Let's assume initially we have a non-extensible string.   You accelerate A until the string becomes taut.   What happens then?
Our magic string supplies whatever force is necessary to keep A and B at a specific distance from each other.   It doesn't matter what A's acceleration is, the string will develop a tension that will decelerate A and accelerate B so they are moving at the same speed.  At any time after that point, the distance is constant and the velocities and accelerations of the blocks are identical.
Now we replace it with an extensible string.   As the distance between the objects reaches the minimum length of the string, tension arises and it places a force on both objects.    But this force is not enough for B to reach the speed of A (at least not instantly).
If the spring constant is low (the string is very stretchy), then the string must get to be very long before it develops much force.   At least for a period of time, the acceleration of A will be more than that of B.
What happens later depends on the spring constant and the acceleration of A.   It could be that the acceleration of B oscillates as the string gains and loses length.
So an inextensible string develops exactly the correct force to keep them a set distance apart.   An extensible string does not and therefore you cannot make any guarantees about what the accelerations of the objects are.
